# Geocoder find nearby suburbs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-geocoder, geocoder

In my rails application I have a table called Suburb which contains the name of suburbs with their respective latitude and longitude.

When I query

```
Suburb.near(@suburb.name, 50, :units => :km).order('distance').map(&:name)
```

It is skipping some suburbs that are nearby

**example:  When I search for suburb near "Brunswick North" it should give me "Brunswick" in the result array as "Brunswick" is around 2km far from "Brunswick North"**

I am not able to figure out why it is happening please help me out with this

Ps: I am using Geocoder gem for finding the nearby suburbs

Comment: what if you use this syntax with proper coordinates? `Suburb.near([40.71, -100.23], 20, :units => :km)`

Comment: It doesn't show me the desired result either